# Safely trash instead of rm

Tags: python, python-3.x, console, unix

This script is called `trash` and it goes on the path.

```
Usage: trash [OPTIONS] [TRASH_FILES]...
```

How clean/readable do you think this is? Is Python the right tool for the job?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys
import shutil
import itertools
from pathlib import Path
import click


first = next


def candidate_names(path):
    '''unused_names('f.txt') yields f.txt, f.txt_1, f.txt_2, ...'''
    yield path
    for i in itertools.count(1):
        yield path.with_name('{path.name}_{i}'.format(**locals()))


default_trash_dir = '~/.trash'

@click.command()
@click.argument('trash_files', nargs=-1)
@click.option('--trash-dir', default='', metavar='<trash_dir>', help=
'''destination for trash. Defaults to ${{TRASH_DIR}}, and then '{}'.'''
              .format(default_trash_dir))
def trash(trash_files, trash_dir):
    '''Safely trash the given files by moving them into a trash_dir.

Files are stored by their path relative to either ~ or / (preferring ~
if possible)

If an existing item with the same name is already in the trash, I
add _1, _2, ... to the end of the filename.

Metadata is copied; See Python documentation on shutil.copy2 for
details.

    \b
    $ touch a
    $ mkdir b
    $ touch b/c
    $ touch /tmp/d
    $ trash a b/c /tmp/d
    /home/sam/subdir/a -> /home/sam/.trash/subdir/a
    /home/sam/subdir/b/c -> /home/sam/.trash/subdir/b/c
    /tmp/d -> /home/sam/.trash/_root/tmp/d
    $ touch a
    $ trash a
    /home/sam/subdir/a -> /home/sam/.trash/subdir/a_1

    '''

    # get/make trashdir
    if not trash_dir:
        # empty-string and non-existence are treated the same way
        trash_dir = os.environ.get('TRASH_DIR', '')
        if not trash_dir:
            trash_dir = default_trash_dir
    trash_path = Path(trash_dir).expanduser()
    trash_path.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)

    for trash_file_ in trash_files:
        trash_file = Path(trash_file_)
        if not trash_file.exists():
            print("{}: not found".format(trash_file))
            sys.exit(1)

        # get absolute path
        trash_file = Path(trash_file_).resolve()

        # get a destination which does not already exist
        try:
            trash_dest_candidate = trash_path / trash_file.relative_to(Path.home())
        except ValueError:
            trash_dest_candidate = trash_path / '_root' / trash_file.relative_to('/')

        trash_dest = first(filter(lambda path: not path.exists(),
                                 candidate_names(trash_dest_candidate)))

        trash_dest.parent.mkdir(exist_ok=True, parents=True)
        print('{} -> {}'.format(trash_file, trash_dest))

        try:
            shutil.move(trash_file, trash_dest)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e))
            sys.exit(2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    trash()
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? I believe it would be easier and best to make an alias for this. A great answer can be found [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/17622/how-can-i-make-rm-move-files-to-the-trash-can).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
first = next
```

That needlessly pollutes the top-level namespace. Please bury that within `def trash`. Also, the `first()` call is odd -- it would be more idiomatic to simply call `next()` when obtaining first element.

```
    '''unused_names('f.txt') yields f.txt, f.txt_1, f.txt_2, ...'''
```

That's a code defect. The comment meant to refer to `candidate_names()`.

You might choose to shift the responsibility, to only `yield` unused names, but the current code is fine, too.

```
    yield path.with_name('{path.name}_{i}'.format(**locals()))
```

Passing in `**locals()` isn't the most readable way. Please just phrase it as

```
    yield path.with_name(f'{path.name}_{i}')
```

Docstring:

```
Metadata is copied; See Python documentation on shutil.copy2 for details.
```

Kudos for delegating to official docs rather than copying a sentence from them. But it's probably better to point to `move()`, which itself points to `copy2()`.

```
\b
```

Not sure what you meant by `\b`.

Maybe you don't need the metavar?

The `trash_file`s can sometimes have long directory paths -- consider using SHA1 to compress the directory down to a short unique string.

```
if not trash_dir:
```

I don't understand why the click default wasn't set to `os.environ.get('TRASH_DIR', '')`.

You have three expressions you want to probe here, call them d1, d2, d3. Rather than if / then, consider using `or`:

```
trash_dir = d1 or d2 or d3
```

Consider phrasing this

```
for trash_file_ in trash_files:
```

as

```
for trash_file in map(Path, trash_files):
```

I like the business of finding `trash_dest_candidate` relative to $HOME or /, whichever works. This could easily be a list of (more than 2) dirs.

```
    try:
        shutil.move(trash_file, trash_dest)
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        sys.exit(2)
```

Catching all exceptions doesn't seem to help you here -- might be better to not catch anything and live with the stack trace. The `str()` is superfluous. Consider calling `exit()` with `errno` from `e`, rather than constant `2`. It appears to me that [Ctrl-C](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.KeyboardInterrupt) is disabled during cross-filesystem file copies.

Overall, it looks like pretty good code that offers a nice service of "collapsing" filenames while avoiding collisions. Consider appending timestamp + pathname to a log file, and automatically pruning month-old files at end of each run, so trash does not grow without bound.